Problem in using the delete operator for an array of objects allocated in heap using a FOR loop instead of using the delete[] array_of_objects keyword
#include <iostream>

class ArrayClass
{
private:
    int *m_Arr;
    int i;

public:
    int Size;
    ArrayClass() : Size(5), i(0), m_Arr(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "The constructor was called." << std::endl;
    }
    ~ArrayClass()
    {
        std::cout << "The destructor was called." << std::endl;
        delete[] m_Arr;
    }
    void InitArr()
    {
        m_Arr = new int[Size];
    }
    void Setter(int &var)
    {
        *(m_Arr + i) = var;
        i++;
    }
    int *Getter() const
    {
        return m_Arr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ArrayClass *instance = new ArrayClass[2];
    std::cout << instance << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        (instance + j)->InitArr();
        for (int i = 1; i <= (instance + j)->Size; i++)
        {
            (instance + j)->Setter(i);
        }
        int *Get = (instance + j)->Getter();
        std::cout << "The numbers are:" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < (instance + j)->Size; i++)
        {
            std::cout << *(Get + i) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++)
    {
        delete (instance + l);
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

I am a beginner in C++, and have ran into a problem, I am trying to use the delete keyword, using the for loop, instead of delete[] instance. I am just trying to keep this method of deleting the instance array in heap, using the pointer arithmetic. But the delete is not doing the work, when I run the program, the destructor code snippet is not printed out on the cmd, the program just terminates, not respecting the line std::cin.get();
Only, doing this works. delete[] instance;.
But, I want this method to be used,
for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++)
    {
        delete (instance + l);
    }

So, can you please rectify the mistake.
Or, is it that the method I am trying to use, even valid in C++

Each delete must match the new that was used to allocate memory. You have one new[] to create instance, but then try to call 3 delete to remove it - that cannot work. delete[] instance outside of any loop is the only allowed way to release instance.

you must read about the rule of 3/5 to understand the next issues you will run into

You don't want to use that method, because it is wrong. Get yourself a good book and stop guessing.

"Only, doing this works. delete[] instance;." because only that is the correct way to delete the array. There isnt much more to it (other than you shouldnt be using new and delete in the first place, but I suppose this is for an exercise)

Also, with pointers (and arrays) *(m_Arr + i) is exactly the same as m_arr[i].

I’m voting to close this question because OP seems to know what is wrong and what is correct but wants the wrong.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, I believe author of question just want to know why his/her method doesn't work. Is it so bad to be curious?

"I am a beginner in C++, and have ran into a problem, I am trying to use the delete keyword" That's your problem right there. new and delete are an advanced topic. If someone is purporting to teach you C++ and is starting with owning raw pointers, they are doing you a disservice.

@SPGC I am not judging anybody. Especially not for being curious. The question could be phrased better. And when I notice that I do mention it. Judge me for that :P

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, nah, I won't do it) just why close question before it receive an answer even if question is poorly phrased?

@SPGC because we are trying to make SO a place with good questions and good answers. Closing questions is not an offense but a necessity

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, well IMHO that's reason why beginners prefer to use chatgpt or copilot, there they'll receive an answer (mostly shity, but usually it's ok for them), here they usually receive a lot of comments about "poorly structure, no outputs, etc" and no answer...

@SPGC they did get their answer, no?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, yeah, but not always they get it and closing questions with IMHO arguably poor phrasing without answers is common practice here. That's my point

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Unfortunately method you want to use isn't valid in C++.
You need to use delete to free memory for object created with new, and delete[] to free memory for array created with new[]. Simple mnemonic - for each new one delete, for each new[] one delete[].
The reason for this that when you create something with new or new[] you allocate a bit more memory than you expect, additional memory is allocated for technical information for delete or delete[] operator. This information specify amount of memory that was allocated and which should be later deleted with operator delete or delete[]. And when you use delete for each element of array allocated with new[] the delete operator looks in a wrong place for technical information and this can lead to undefined behavior.
This is simple explanation, for more precise I advice you to look on cppreference.com, but for the beginning I believe this explanation is enough
